# Making client apps for my .net core web app

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-core

I have made a .net core 2.2 app and it works great, I can browse to it through my browser and all of the stuff I made works. I am wondering if it is possible to make an app for my phone though instead of getting to my server through the browser. I mainly want to do this so that I have a better phone side layout. Is this possible and if so could you point me to a good starting point to figure out how to make something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at Xamarin perhaps?

Xamarin is a free open-source framework to build truely native cross-platform mobile apps using C# .NET for iOS, Android or Windows. It runs on Mono and .NET to build apps with native performance and native UI.

Xamarin allows you to develop native apps using C# language and platform specfic tools/SDKs and share the same code across multiple platforms - iOS, Android or Windows.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/